# Adding values to dataframe in cycle

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, cycle

There are 3 lists of values:
`dates = [1,2,3] (number of weeks) stores = [101,102,103] (number of stores) items = [12344,4544] (number of stores)`

And there is an empty df with the same columns [date,stores,items]. So i have to add data from 3 lists above to the empty df. Data adding logic:

1. date. Each number of week must be added len(stores)*len(items) times(6 times in example)
2. stores. each number of stores must be added len(items) times(2) for each date.
3. items. All items item by item

date    stores  items
1   101 12344
1   101 4544
1   102 12344
1   102 4544
1   103 12344
1   103 4544
2   101 12344
2   101 4544
2   102 12344
2   102 4544
2   103 12344
2   103 4544
3   101 12344
3   101 4544
3   102 12344
3   102 4544
3   103 12344
3   103 4544

As a result we need to receive unique date/stores/item strings. In a real task, the length of the initial lists will be several thousand, so it is important to build on the length of each of them and not on the actual values ​​when filling df.
Hope i was clear explaining it) How is it can be done ? Thank you in advance

I've tried to write many alike cycles but there is no result. Googled much info but still cant find(or cant understand) the answer.

```
`a=["A","B","C"]
b=[155,155,155]
x = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    x += [a[i]]*b[i]
print(x)

x = []
for i in range(len(date)):
    x += [date[i]]*b[i]
df['date'] = x`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = [1, 2, 3]
stores = [101, 102, 103]
items = [12344, 4544]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[d, s, i] for d in dates for s in stores for i in items],
    columns=['dates', 'stores', 'items'])
df  # as in your example
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example would be to use append:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=[1,2,3])
df.append({1:2,2:3,3:4}, ignore_index=True)
```

Another way would be to create a new df and just concat it.

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({1:dates, 2:stores, 3:items+[None]})])
```